# Invalid API response while removing public links for a document (though the action is performed)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, links

I'm noticing a strange API behavior where the action goes through but the errors say

> Bad request.

This was working fine 4 days back. Now, it is returning the following response

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Nullable object must have a value."}}}
```

**URL**

```
https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/some_user_abc_com/_api/SP.Web.DeleteAnonymousLinkForObject
```

**BODY**

```
{"url": "https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/some_user_abc_com/Documents/Mauze-why.txt","removeAssociatedSharingLinkGroup": true, "isEditLink": false}
```

but the action goes through.

Any reason for this?